# Output of command "file <filename>" changes after opening the file with nano?

Tags: files, raspberry-pi, ascii

**Background**: I'm running a script on a raspberry pi, and the script writes logs to a file. The script take some time to finish so sometimes the pi experiences power outage and shuts down. Whenever this happens, more often than not, the log file will lose a few lines, and some null bytes seem to be appended to the end of the log.

**Goal**: I'm trying detect this type of situations. When I check out the log I can see a bunch of "^@^@" characters, which I gathered represents null bytes. I tried using the `file` command, and pleasantly discovered that a normal log returns "ASCII text", while a "corrupted" one returns "data".

**Problem**: I thought this would work, but it seems like if I hadn't opened the file (e.g. with nano), then even the corrupted file returns "ASCII text". Only after I view it with an editor, it becomes "data"... Any idea why this is happening? And is there a robust solution to detect this kind of situation?

Thanks!

EDIT: One important thing I have forgotten to include (because I also just realized this): The first time, when it returned "ASCII text", the ending of the file was "^@^@", while the second time, when it returned "data", the ending was "^@^@xxx" (a few letters appended). Not sure if this makes a difference.

EDIT 2: Yes, I have confirmed that with a "corrupted" file, if I just check the file type, it returns "ASCII text", but if I `echo "xxxx" >> the_file`, that file becomes "data"... So, my solution for now is to echo some characters into the file before checking the file type... Still curious about the reason behind this though.

Comment: Very strange. I generated a text file with some raw (non-character) bytes at the end, and even with a few actual letters, and `file my_file` always returns `data`.

Could you give us a reproducable sample?

Comment: I'd use `bvi` or `od` see how the file changes.  The problem, though, must lie in the library which `files` calls, the aptly named `libmagic`.  You might consider grepping for null bytes as a test for corruption instead of using `files`.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs folks! It's surprisingly hard to generate a sharable sample when I want to do it on purpose... been unplugging my pi for the past half an hour and it's just not yielding a file that I want.. Will checkout grepping for nulls though!